# Salesforce API with Azure AD SSO and On Behalf of Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, salesforce

I have my Salesforce organization configured to use SSO through Azure Active Directory.  Now I'm trying to use Azure AD and the 'On Behalf of Flow' to authenticate to the Salesforce REST API.

[image: On Behalf of Flow]

The Salesforce REST API would be Web API B in this diagram.

For the Setup of API A in the diagram I have added the `user_impersonation` permission for Salesforce and have granted Admin Consent for it.

[image: API A Permissions]

I'm able to successfully authenticate to API A and complete the token exchange, and receive a token for salesforce.  However when calling salesforce using the token I get back from Azure AD, I receive a 401 unauthorized.

This is the code I'm using on Web API A to exchange for the Salesforce Access Token

```
//Get the original JWT From the header
var authZhdr = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key.Equals("Authorization"));
var token = authZhdr.Value.FirstOrDefault().Substring(7);

//Exchange original JWT for Salesforce Token
IConfidentialClientApplication clnt = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(_config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId"))
    .WithClientSecret(_config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientSecret"))
    .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMyOrg)
    .WithTenantId(_config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId"))
    .Build();
UserAssertion ua = new UserAssertion(token);

var res = clnt.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new string[] { "https://<my-org>-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/user_impersonation" }, ua).ExecuteAsync().Result;

var access_token = res.AccessToken

var http = new HttpClient();
http.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://<my-org>-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/");
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthorizationRequestHeader("Bearer", access_token);

var resp = await http.GetAsync("/sobjects/Account");

Console.Log(resp.StatusCode)  //401 Unauthorized
```

I've also confirmed this on-behalf-of flow works with the Microsoft Graph API, just not with Salesforce.

I've checked the User Profile in Salesforce and it has API Access enabled. Is there anything additional within Salesforce that needs to be configured to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I'm happy to provide further diagrams of the APIs and configurations within azure if needed, but everything seems to be working up until the Salesforce API call.

Comment: Consider cross-posting to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. How does the token look like? Should be `org_id!semi random rubbish` where `org_id` you can compare with salesforce setup->company information. Does this thing actually login to Salesforce or try to reuse some cached tokens? Maybe the session id expired. If you don't go far with it - maybe look into JWT Bearer flow, no password needed and should work whether you have SSO or not.

Comment: The token I get back from AAD definitely doesn't have an ! in it, so I'm guessing that is an issue.
I'm looking into the JWT Bearer flow now.  I just saw and example of the On Behalf of flow and thought that 'use case' fit better.

Comment: I ended up using the JWT Bearer flow to access salesforce.  

I think I was making some assumptions about what Azure AD was doing when exchanging tokens.  Thinking that maybe Azure AD could handle doing the [SAML Assertion Flow]( https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5) and just give me an access token to salesforce. 

Maybe that is possible in some fashion, but it wasn't readily apparent in any of the tutorials or documentation i looked at.